# How to highlight searched queries in result page of Django template?

Tags: python, css, django

I have the following search query in `views.py`:

```
class SearchView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query) |
                Q(content__icontains=query)
            ).distinct()
        context = {
            'queryset': queryset,
            'query': query,
        }
        return render(request, 'blogs/search_result.html', context)
```

and if I search a word like `Tesla` the results shown in result template is as below:

[image]

Please help me, how do I highlight the searched query in yellow color in Django templates? Thank you for help!

edit:
This is the template code with search box

```
<div class="card my-4">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-title">Search blog</div>
        <form action="{% url 'blog:search_blog' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-3">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the template for result_search

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container bg-light w-100">
    <h2 class="display-6 border-bottom py-3">Results for "{{ query }}"</h2>
    {% for post in queryset %}
    <div class="my-1">
        <a class="link" href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you

Edit 2: Daniel Roseman, Sir this is the html below I highlighted it in yellow.
[image]

Comment: Please, share your template so we can see what you're doing there and help you then.

Comment: I just added templates

Comment: Here's [my answer the the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834159/split-by-a-word-case-insensitive/64553606#64553606) that does exactly that the topic asks.

Comment: here's [my answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64553606/10815638) that does exactly what the topic asks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do this in a template filter. Something like:

```
@register.filter
def highlight_search(text, search):
    highlighted = text.replace(search, '<span class="highlight">{}</span>'.format(search)
    return mark_safe(highlighted)
```

Now in your template you can do:

```
{% load my_tags %} # wherever you put the template filter

{% for post in queryset %}
<div class="my-1">
    <a class="link" href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title|highlight_search:query }}</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

You'd need to send the search_text back with the context that renders the result page.

Comment: Thank your sir, I didn't understand `You'd need to send the search_text back with the context that renders the result page.`

maybe that is why I am getting this error: `VariableDoesNotExist at /search-blog/
`
Please help me fix it

Comment: I realize that your view sends the variable `query`, that's what you need to use - updated.

Comment: Almost done sir, a tiny problem here, it highlights extra characters other than `tesla` please see above, I updated my question, and added the html and how it looks.

Comment: Sorry again, should have been `search` in the format for the replacement text, updated once more.

Comment: In case it's useful to anyone, to do case-insensitive matching, replace the third line with: `highlighted = re.sub('(?i)(%s)' % (re.escape(search)), '<span class="highlight">\\1</span>', text)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a function from **django-haystack** but you will need to configure the simple backend on your settings:

`pipenv install django-haystack`

Your `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'haystack'
)

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
}
```

Create a new template filter:

```
@register.filter
def highlight_search(text, search):
    from haystack.utils.highlighting import Highlighter
    highlight = Highlighter(search, html_tag='strong', css_class='highlighted', max_length=400)

    return highlight.highlight(text)
```

Your template will look something like this:

```
{{ result.htmldata|highlight_search:myquery|safe  }}
```

The built-in `safe` will render the html_tag that you choose on your implementation.

More info: https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/highlighting.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `backgroud-color` for the `div` in which search results are being appended like

```
.link {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```