# How do I highlight a particular word from a column inside a text using django?

Tags: django

So let's say I have 3 columns.

Text                          | Subject         | connector

Cancer is caused by windmills.| cancer, windmill| caused by

These are all saved inside a postgreSQL database. How do I highlight the words, cancer and windmill (from subject) and caused by (from connector), inside the text and display it on the webpage?

```py
{% if db.cause and db.connector in db.text %}
<td><mark>{{ db.text }}</mark></td>
```

But this highlights the whole text instead of those 4 words cancer, windmill and caused by.

Update from @selcuk's suggestion:

in templatetags/filters.py:

```py
@register.filter
def highlight(text, search):
    highlighted = text.replace(search, '<mark>{}</mark>'.format(search))
    return mark_safe(highlighted)
```

in page.html:

```
{% for db in context %}
  {% if db.cause and db.connector in db.text %}
  {% with cause=db.cause %}
  <td style="word-wrap: break-all">{{ db.text|highlight:cause }}</td>
  {% endwith %}
  {% else %}
  <td style="word-wrap: break-all">{{ db.text }}</td>
  {% endif %}
```

End result: Nothing is highlighted and no error messages.

Desired Output: Only Cancer, caused by and windmill to be highlighted

Comment: This is not a trivial task. I'd suggest you to write a custom template filter. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128231/how-to-highlight-searched-queries-in-result-page-of-django-template) for a start.

Comment: I did try that method however the end result was that it highlighted the space between each letter. For e.g.` c a n c e r  i s  c a u s e d  b y  w i n d m i l l. ` So each space between every letter gets highlighted instead.

Comment: From your description it sounds like the value of the `search` argument passed to your filter function is an empty string. Print the value of `db.cause` inside your `{% for %}` loop to confirm that it is not empty.

Comment: I've checked and yes certain rows does not have any cause or connectors. But for those rows that do, the highlight doesn't appear. Right now it just displays everything as it is without any highlights. I've updated my code.

Comment: Please test your filter with some static text first, such as `{{ "foo bar baz"|highlight:"bar" }}` to see if it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace() has been changed to re.sub because replace() is unable to handle case insensitive words/characters.

In templatetags/filters.py:

```py
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
import re

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def highlight(text, search):
    search = re.split((" "), search)

    for i in search:
        highlighted = re.sub(i, '<span style="background-color: #000FF">{}</span>'.format(i), text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        text = highlighted
    return mark_safe(text)
```