# How to highlight searched queries in result page by using Function based views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm searching "keyword" in title & content of blog, it returns the result as expected but i want to highlight the searched words. How could i do that? I referred
[stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128231/how-to-highlight-searched-queries-in-result-page-of-django-template) but that was implemented in class based views. How could i do it using function based views?

views.py:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('user_search_input')

    if query:
        results = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(content__icontains=query))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Access denied")
    context={
    'results' : results,
    'search_word' : query
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/search.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
```

I have created custom template tag,

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def highlight_search(text, search):
    highlighted = text.replace(search, '<span class="highlight">{}</span>'.format(search))
    return mark_safe(highlighted)
```

[image: my folders structure is,]

search.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load search_highlighter %}
{% block content %}
      <h3 >Search results for <strong><em>"{{ search_word }}"</em></strong></h3>
      {% for result in results %}
          <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' result.id %}">{{ result.title | highlight_search:search_word }}</a></h2>
          <p class="article-content">{{ result.content | safe | truncatewords:"50" | highlight_search : search_word }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the answers to the linked question that require class based views. You've passed the search term to your template context, so the accepted answer (a custom template filter) should work fine. If it's not, please share your filter definition and relevant template code.

Comment: updated the code, please see the edit in question

Comment: So what is the problem? Any Python errors? Are the `span`s with the `highlight` class appearing in the DOM? (If so, then the problem is with whatever CSS you're trying to apply to this class.) You're expected to do some basic debugging before coming to SO.

Comment: it works after clearing cache, a huge blunder. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: If you're using postgres you should have a look at the full text search fields in Django. It doesn't have highlighting built in but it's trivial to add (it's built into postgres, you just need to write the query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with browser cache, I have cleared cookies & cache, it works as expected.