# Case-folding the Partition Method in Python?

Tags: python, partition, case-folding

How can I separate a string irregardless of upper or lower case?

```
line = 'Thing Replaces OtherThing'
before, sep, after = line.partition(' replaces ')
print(before)
print(after)
```

I expect the output to be "Thing" and "OtherThing".

Edit:
I also need it to work with no spaces in the string

```
line = 'ThingReplacesOtherThing'
before, sep, after = line.partition('replaces')
```

Comment: You've sadly exhausted the reasonable use cases for plain `str` methods, so you'll want a regex, which the duplicate covers. It's *technically* possible to do with `str` methods, but so ugly I'd prefer the regex. The ugly solution would be: `beforelen, _, afterlen = map(len, line.casefold().partition(' replaces '))`, then slice the original `line` based on those partitioned component lengths, e.g. following up with `before, sep, after = line[:beforelen], line[beforelen:-afterlen], line[-afterlen:]`), but I can't *recommend* tricky code like that in good conscience.

Comment: Just for fun, I did [post this solution to the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72405738/364696). I don't expect any up-votes for it. :-)